# How to create advanced search in ruby on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, advanced-search

Is there any gem or method to do "Advanced Search" in rails 4.0.0 ?

Answer (score 1):

Railscasts have an episode on [Advanced Search Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form)
The [revised version](http://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised) is built for Rails 4 - though you'll need a Pro account ($9 a month) to watch it).

Comment: it would be great if someone describe that solution, it looks like an ad to me.

Comment: No it is not an ad. Advanced search forms is accessible to anyone. You need a pro account to get to the other one - you might be seeing the requirement to pay for the pro account.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use an engine like [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) you could use the [Sunspot gem](http://sunspot.github.io/).